# "This value is not valid" when saving a comma-including number in Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, validation, numbers, sonata

I am developing a CMS using Sonata and Symfony 3.

I have used the JavaScript AutoNumeric library to force a numeric field to contain commas, in an effort to make the app more user-friendly.

The problem is that now when I try to save a record, the server flags the field with a "this value is not valid" message. Here is the annotation I am using on the field:

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", scale=2, precision=12, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "validator.not_blank")
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 0,
 *      max = 9999999999
 * )
 */
```

Is there a way to tell my server-side validator to strip out commas before validating?

===

Edit #1: This field is using the NumberType as its type. Here is the relevant admin code:

```
        ->add(
            'amount',
            NumberType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'list.label.salary.amount',
                'scale'=> 2,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    "class" => "compensation-number",
                ),
            )
        )
```

My JavaScript creates a new AutoNumeric instance with the form field as its input element.

Edit #2: In other words, this field is being treated as a string in the browser, and I need to convert that value into a float before it can be stored in the database. I'm not sure how best to do that.

Comment: Numbers don't contain commas, strings do, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: could you please include the exact record you're trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up duplicating the field in my Twig template, then using JavaScript to hide the "real" input. I then had a JavaScript listener update the "real" value with a cleaned-up version of the formatted number visible to users. That fixed my problem.